# Speeding up code and screen flickering using screenupdating

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a macro where I download data into Excel from a software database through an array formula. The scope of the macro is to input a start date and the data is written to individual Excel files and then saved away.
Unfortunately the macro is very slow although I am using the usual code lines to speed up the macro.
Another problem is that the array formula constantly expands the `UsedRange` with empty lines and thus the file gets bigger and bigger. To counteract this, I delete the empty lines within a `For Next` loop. Last but not least I still have screen flickering. My guess is the use of `DoEvents` but I need it for the update of the array formula.Otherwise the code will continue without having the data downloaded.

Below is my code:

```
Sub Update()

Dim wbTarget As Workbook
Dim objWsInput As Worksheet, objWsMakro As Worksheet, objWsDerivative, objWsFile
Dim Inbox1 As Variant
Dim strFormula As String, strFilename As String, strDate As String
Dim lngDate As Long
Dim dDay As Date

Set objWsInput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("INPUT")

'Input start date
Inbox1 = InputBox("Geben Sie bitte ein Start-Datum ein!", Default:=Format(Date, "DD.MM.YYYY"))

Call EventsOff

For dDay = DateSerial(Year(Inbox1), Month(Inbox1), Day(Inbox1)) To DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now))
    If Weekday(dDay) <> 1 And Weekday(dDay) <> 7 Then

        'Convert date into DateValue & string
        strDate = Format(dDay, "YYYYMMDD")
        lngDate = DateValue(dDay)


        'Delete contents
        With objWsInput
            .Activate
            .UsedRange.ClearContents

            'Set array formula for QPLIX
            strFormula = "=DisplayAllocationWithPreset(""5a9eb7ae2c94dee7a0d0fd5c"", ""5b06a1832c94de73b4194ccd"", " & lngDate & ")"
            .Range("A1").FormulaArray = strFormula

            'Wait until refresh is done
            Do
            DoEvents
            Loop While Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone

            'Copy paste
            .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
            .Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

            'Call last row and delete depth 0 with number format
            i = 2
            Call LastRow
            For i = CountRow To 2 Step -1
                If .Cells(i, 1) = 0 Then .Rows(i).Delete
            Next i

            Call NumberFormat

            'Set file name
            strFilename = "Y:\Risikomanagement\Mandate Positions\QPLIX_Mandate_Positions_" & strDate & ".xlsx"

            'Open file
            Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Add
            Set objWsFile = wbTarget.Worksheets(1)

            'Copy data into new file
            .Range("C1:J" & .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count).Copy Destination:=objWsFile.Range("A1")

            'Save file
            wbTarget.SaveAs Filename:=strFilename
            wbTarget.Close

            Call DeleteBlankRows

        End With

    End If

Next dDay


'Save Workbook
ActiveWorkbook.Save

Call EventsOn

MsgBox "Upload Files erstellt!", vbInformation, "Hinweis"

End Sub
```

The support functions are as followed:

```
Public Sub EventsOff()

'Events ausschalten
With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.EnableEvents = False
.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
.DisplayAlerts = False
End With

End Sub

Public Sub EventsOn()

'Events anschalten
With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True
.EnableEvents = True
.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
.DisplayAlerts = True
End With

End Sub
```

To complete my code here are the parts for deleting empty rows & formatting the numbers:

```
Sub DeleteBlankRows()

Dim MyRange As Range
Dim iCounter As Long

Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

For iCounter = MyRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1

    'Step 4: If entire row is empty then delete it.
    If Application.CountA(Rows(iCounter).EntireRow) = 0 Then
        Rows(iCounter).Delete
    End If

Next iCounter

End Sub

Sub NumberFormat()

Dim r As Range

For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If IsNumeric(r) Then
       r.Value = CDec(r.Value)
       r.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    End If
Next r

End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated.Thank you in advance.

Rgds

Comment: I could be overlooking it, but.....are you not using application.screenupdating = False? Surely your screenflickering is in the past then.

Comment: @JvdV - Sorry I updated my question. The support functions were not correct...

Comment: I think it would work better for you if you used the [method from this great site](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm) to find the last row and/or last column in your sheet. Deleting a lot of rows every loop is not helping the flicker for sure

Comment: `LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` and 
`LastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `DoEvents` disables the usual speed up procedures like:

```
.ScreenUpdating = False
.EnableEvents = False
.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

I changed my code including the support function `Call Events Off` directly after `DoEvents` loop and the flickering disappeared. The whole process was also much faster.